# g++ 4.8.1 on Ubuntu can't compile large bitsets

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stl, bitset

My source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef unsigned long long U64;
const U64 MAX = 8000000000L;

struct Bitmap
{
  void insert(U64 N) {this->s.set(N % MAX);}
  bool find(U64 N) const {return this->s.test(N % MAX);}
private:
  std::bitset<MAX> s;
};

int main()
{
  cout << "Bitmap size: " << sizeof(Bitmap) << endl;
  Bitmap* s = new Bitmap();
  // ...
}
```

Compilation command and its output:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -O4  tc002.cpp -o latest 
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

Bug report and its fix will take long time... Has anybody had this problem already? Can I manipulate some compiler flags or something else (in source probably) to bypass this problem?

I'm compiling on Ubuntu, which is actually VMware virtual machine with 12GB memory and 80GB disk space, and host machine is MacBook Pro:

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: you realize that bitset is a fixed-sized array, and that you're allocating 64GB to it, right?

Comment: @JoshG79 - you are mistaken, the bitset size in this example is exactly 1000000000 bytes, which is less than 1GB. If I change the constant MAX to 4000000000L (it's half of what is in this example), it compiles and works fine.

Comment: The compiler has used up all of your memory and was killed by the OS. You can try `--use-less-memory` flag, but I doubt it will work.

Comment: Maybe the stack can not hold an internal compiler temporary Bitmap for the operator new

Comment: @n.m. - I don't see this option. `g++ --help=params` doesn't show anything like that

Comment: @n.m. - I'm having a sad, sarcastic smile

Comment: By the way, std::vector<bool> with predefined size = 10000000000UL is compiled fine and even works

Comment: There is already a bug report at gcc's bugzilla [Gcc uses large amounts of memory and processor power with large C++11 bitsets](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56671)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my machine, g++ 4.8.1 needs a maximum of about 17 gigabytes of RAM to compile this file, as observed with `top`.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
18287 nm        20   0 17.880g 0.014t    808 D  16.6 95.7   0:17.72 cc1plus
```

't' in the RES column stands for terabytes ;)

The time taken is

```
real    1m25.283s
user    0m31.279s
sys     0m5.819s
```

In the C++03 mode, g++ compiles the same file using just a few megabytes. The time taken is

```
real    0m0.107s
user    0m0.074s
sys     0m0.011s
```

I would say this is definitely a bug. A workaround is to give the machine more RAM, or enable swap. Or use `clang++`.

Comment: Yes, removal the option -std=c++11 has helped me too, at least in testing extremes for the std::bitset. Of course, in real software development today this step back is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

[Comment]

This little thing:

```
#include <bitset>
int main() {
    std::bitset<8000000000UL> b;
}
```

results in 'virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory' when compiled with
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

Comment: So, it's compiler-wide long-standing thing. GCC developers, please take a look!